# How to use results from $.getJSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

## Solved:

I was able to solve the problem by wrapping my interior of the `tweetSweep` function inside a callback function (snippet below).

This works but I'd love to hear if there are other approaches available.

```js
    // URL Constructor ---------- //
    tweetSweep: function() {
      this.getShortUrl(function(short) {
        for(var i = 0; i < s.tweets.length; i++) {
          
          var tweet = $(s.tweets[i]);
          var tweet_text = $(tweet).text();
          
          // Build the URL
          $(tweet).attr({
            href: s.tweet_url + tweet_text + ' ' + short + s.tweet_source,
            target: '_blank'
            });
          }
      });
    },

    // URL Shortening via Bitly API ---------- //
    getShortUrl: function(callback) {
       var accessToken = s.bitly_key;
       var url = 'https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?access_token=' + accessToken + '&longUrl=' + s.post_url;

        $.getJSON(url, function(response) {
            callback(response.data.url);
        });
    }
```

---

## Original question:

I'm working on a small "Tweet This" plugin that will take any text wrapped in a `a` element with a class of `.tweet-embed` and build a Twitter link with the sentence and a shortened URL of the current page via the bit.ly API.

I'm calling the `getShortURL` function via my `init` function, and I'm trying to append the result of it to the href attribute of my links in the `tweetSweep` function (via the `shorturl` variable, which is currently undefined... line 39):

```js
(function() {

  /**
   * Main TweetEmbed object with settings
   * and helper functions to build "Tweet this"
   * links around desired text.
   * 
   * @type {Object}
   */
  
  var TweetEmbed = {

    // Settings ---------- //
    settings: {
      tweets: $('.tweet-embed'),
      tweet_url: 'http://twitter.com/home/?status=',
      tweet_source: ' — @handle',
      post_url: window.location.href,
      bitly_login: 'my_login_is_here',
      bitly_key: 'my_key_is_here'
    },

    // Initialization ---------- //
    init: function() {
      s = this.settings;
      this.tweetSweep();
      this.getShortUrl(s.post_url);
    },

    // URL Constructor ---------- //
    tweetSweep: function() {
      for(var i = 0; i < s.tweets.length; i++) {
        
        var tweet = $(s.tweets[i]);
        var tweet_text = $(tweet).text();
        
        // Build the URL
        $(tweet).attr({
          //href: s.tweet_url + tweet_text + s.tweet_source + shorturl,
          href: s.tweet_url + tweet_text + s.tweet_source,
          target: '_blank'
          });
        }
    },

    // URL Shortening via Bitly API ---------- //
    getShortUrl: function(url, callback) {
       var accessToken = s.bitly_key;
       var url = 'https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?access_token=' + accessToken + '&longUrl=' + encodeURIComponent(url);

        $.getJSON(url, function(response) {
            short = response.data.url;
        });
    }

  }; // end TweetEmbed

  // Fire off TweetEmbed's initialization 
  TweetEmbed.init();
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="tweet-embed">Test tweet here</a>
```

When I call my `getShortUrl();` function, if I type in `short` in the console, it will spit out the shortened URL as expected. My issue is that I can't figure out how to use that response anywhere else in my plugin (I was trying to save it to a `shorturl` variable in my `init` to no avail)...

I've searched over and over and have found tons of advice for similar issues, but still haven't been able to figure out how to apply it to my code. I'm pretty clueless when it comes to all this asynchronous and callback jazz.

Comment: You need to pass a callback to `getShortUrl()` that does what you want with the response, and `getShortUrl()` need to call the callback in the `$.getJSON()` callback function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tweetSweet` can take an optional `shorturl` argument, which it defaults to an empty string. Then in your `$.getJSON` callback, you can call `tweetSweep` to update all the URLs with the response from the API.

```js
(function() {

  /**
   * Main TweetEmbed object with settings
   * and helper functions to build "Tweet this"
   * links around desired text.
   *
   * @type {Object}
   */

  var TweetEmbed = {

    // Settings ---------- //
    settings: {
      tweets: $('.tweet-embed'),
      tweet_url: 'http://twitter.com/home/?status=',
      tweet_source: ' — @handle',
      post_url: window.location.href,
      bitly_login: 'my_login_is_here',
      bitly_key: 'my_key_is_here'
    },

    // Initialization ---------- //
    init: function() {
      s = this.settings;
      this.tweetSweep();
      this.getShortUrl(s.post_url);
    },

    // URL Constructor ---------- //
    tweetSweep: function(shorturl) {
      if (!shorturl) {
        shorturl = '';
      }
      for (var i = 0; i < s.tweets.length; i++) {

        var tweet = $(s.tweets[i]);
        var tweet_text = $(tweet).text();

        // Build the URL
        $(tweet).attr({
          href: s.tweet_url + tweet_text + s.tweet_source + shorturl,
          target: '_blank'
        });
      }
    },

    // URL Shortening via Bitly API ---------- //
    getShortUrl: function(url) {
      var accessToken = s.bitly_key;
      var url = 'https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?access_token=' + accessToken + '&longUrl=' + encodeURIComponent(url);
      var self = this;

      $.getJSON(url, function(response) {
        var short = response.data.url;
        self.tweetSweep(short);
      });
    }

  }; // end TweetEmbed

  // Fire off TweetEmbed's initialization 
  TweetEmbed.init();
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="tweet-embed">Test tweet here</a>
```

Comment: I will try and implement this and see how it works. Can you speak to any advantages/disadvantages compared to the new snippet I posted in my question (where I do all the tweetSweep within the getShortURL call)? Just trying to learn more. Thanks man!

Comment: That's another way to do it, and I considered writing a version of my answer that used the `callback` argument to `getShortUrl` similarly.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you trying to use it in your plugin exactly? One option is to use promises

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn802826(v=vs.94).aspx

instead of callbacks, since $.getJSON returns a promise.

Comment: I'm trying to add it to to the `tweetSweep` function (line 39, currently commented out; the idea is to add the response at the end of the URL that is being built there via a "shorturl" variable).